# support AM/PM time format as well as 24 hour

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a regex like so:

```
/(\d\d?[\/-]\d\d?[\/-]\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g
```

this currently supports a string that looks like this:`16/05/14 09:38:22: Jons Janssen: Yo.`

I need it to support `16/05/14 11:19:33 pm: Jons Janssen: Yo Bas.` As well.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex like so:

```
(\d\d?[\/-]\d\d?[\/-]\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?: [ap]m)?): ([^:]+): (.*)
```

`(?: [ap]m)?` is a non-capturing group that matches either `am` or `pm`. The `?` at the end indicates that the whole group is optional.

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE4sL0/2)

Comment: Ah that's nice! I need to include the am/pm in the output string tho, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Damn you're fast! upvoted and will set it to answered in 4 mins.

Comment: @bdv: Glad to have helped! Just a minor note: Add the `i` modifier if you want to also catch `AM` and `PM` as well. I've added it in the demo, but just wanted to make sure... :)